# Почему функция в Слайдере (OnValueChanged) срабатывает сразу при старте?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Собственно, почему функция при этом запускается сразу при старте, а не исключительно после изменения значения слайдера? У меня вот есть слайдер для уровня громкости звуков и при изменении значения у меня стоит функция, которая воспроизводит звук, чтобы было понятно как меняется громкость сразу же, но этот же звук срабатывает сразу при запуске сцены (срабатывает функция), а не только когда трогаю слайдер - почему так и как от этого избавиться? Нигде ответ не нашел (((

Answer (score 0):

В компоненте `Audio Source` твоего объекта со скриптом стоит галочка `Play On Awake`, просто убери её, она отвечает за воспроизведение звука при старте.

Comment: Если бы все было так просто - я бы даже не спрашивал. А если бы Вы были более внимательным - то прочитали бы, что проблема именно в срабатывании указанной функции, а не просто проигрывании звука..

Comment: @skroliks проверь, не изменяется ли значение при старте, просто выведи значение громкости на текст и отслеживай изменения с помощью него